# Loop an Entity Reference Vocabulary Field

Tags: 7, rules

So working through my rule I would like to use a loop to execute an action.

In my content type I have an entity reference to a vocabulary called "Contacts".

I want to loop through all the entity's in that field; however, in the loop LIST date selector it will not let me select just the field, it keeps wanting to drill down further to vocabulary, parent etc ...

`field-contact` is the entity reference to the vocabulary

[image]

It seems to work if the list is just a regular field list on the content type itself but not when it's an entity reference to a taxonomy vocabulary.

Any tips/suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: your question is confusing, please try to make it more undesrtandable

Comment: How is it confusing? The loop will not let me use the vocabulary entity reference field by itself. As seen in the screenshot, it's making me use node:field-contact:parent ect.. and not just node:field-contact. I tried using node:field-contact:parent but it throws a bunch of errors in the rules watchdogs. My question is what am I doing wrong and if there any pointers to try and get this working.

Comment: add a condition: entity has field-> your ER field, then it will be avilable